# how can I switch a component in place of the previous one?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular5

My code looks in the way shown below. I added only the most important code from selected files. Can you show me how I can switch the component `sign-in.component.html` after clicking `Forgot Password?` or `Do not have an account?` to the component `forgot.component.html` or `sign-up.component.html?` The most important thing is to switch component in place of the previous one. So I don't want to route to another page after clicking button. I just want to change one component embed in the page to another one.

index.html:

```
    </head>
    <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    </body>
    </html>
app.component.html:
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer *ngIf="removeFooter()"></app-footer>
```

home.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="isSignIn()">
  <app-sign-in></app-sign-in>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isSignUp()">
  <app-sign-up></app-sign-up>
</div>

<div *ngIf="isForgotPassword()">
  <app-forgot-password></app-forgot-password>
</div>
```

home.component.ts:

```
  constructor() {
      this.signin = true;
      this.signup = false;
      this.forgot = false;
    }

  isSignUp() {
    if (this.signup === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  isSignIn() {
    if (this.signin === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  isForgotPassword() {
    if (this.forgot === true) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

sign-in.component.html:

```
<div class="content-center">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="title-brand">

      <div align="center">

        <input style="background-color: black; border-color: white; color:white; width: 270px" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="USERNAME">

        <br>

        <input style="background-color: black; border-color: white; color:white; width: 270px" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="PASSWORD">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <br>
            <button style="background-color: black; border-color: white; color:white; width: 270px" type="button"  class="btn btn-danger">Log in</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br>

        <h6  style = "color: white" [routerLink]="['/main']" skipLocationChange class=pointer>Forgot Password?</h6>
        <h6 style="color: white" [routerLink]="['/sign-up']" class=pointer>Don't have an account?</h6>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to use routes, as they are designed to do just this.

However if you are set on doing it dynamically then I suggest you check out the docs:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: I didn't write that I don't want to use routes. I use them to route between my other components. But I route whole pages not only one component embed in another one and I am not sure whether it is possible, is it? If yes could you show me example how it should be done?

Comment: Yes you can route between components.  Read a tutorial on routes with children, [something like this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/child_routes.html), or [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/nested-routes/).  If you still need help I will edit my answer, but please try it first as routes are fundamental to angular.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I did everything what I wanted using `children routing` and `skipLocationChange`

Comment: @user9645789 glad I could point you in the right direction.  You can thank me by marking the answer as correct :)